# How to get a column from one table and insert into another table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

If for example I have these tables:

- Table: tableA, Columns: (tableA_id, name, ...)
- Table: **tableB**, Columns: (tableB_id, *cost*, ...) [Foreign key: tableA]
- Table: tableC, Columns: (tableC_id, name, ...)
- Table: tableD, Columns: (tableD_id, dates, ...) [Foreign keys:
  **tableB** & tableC]

How can I get *cost* column from tableB into tableD? Or you actually get the *cost* column when running the application into the grid?

Comment: For getting better answers: 1) write a title that is specific to your question. 2) have 1 question per question (this is a Q&A forum, not a discussion one). 3) create a less abstract example  I might sound like a dick but follow my suggestions and you will get better result. HTH

Comment: Ok, thanks LosManos just followed your steps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem..

Answer1:

```
SELECT ghi.cost, xyz.* FROM [tableXYZ] xyz inner join [tableGHI] ghi on [tableXYZ].[tableXYZ] = [tableGHI].[tableXYZ_FK]
```

and Answer2:

The better way is you create new PK that is not equal with your other table FK. A primary key is handle of your table and you use it for manage your data in your code.

Comment: Thanks Mehdi Yeganeh, I still have to try this.

Does the syntax go into my vb.net application or into sql server?

Comment: Do you actually know where and how to write this in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 as I am new? or can direct me to a link?

Comment: in your Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, you should connect to your database engine and then click on new query and then write you sql queries and for makeing db or table right click on Databases folder and make db and for make table right click on your table or use sql query